# Migrating client wp site for local development

Tags: wordpress

I've been asked to help out with a former colleague of mine's Wordpress Site. Nothing crazy, just change the format of a page, and add some kind of form on another page. I'm not so concerned with these changes I need to make, but am more concerned with setting up an identical site locally so that I can exercise these changes, do whatever I need to do, then simply upload my changes.

Quick background of myself; web developer of about 5 years with strengths in the Javascript frameworks and Node sphere. I know what Wordpress is and can navigate through the project with relative ease. Where I fall short is uncertainty in the project set up side of things.

So I have both the project itself and an export of my clients database, and configuration is updated accordingly. When I attempt to run the site I'm constantly prompted with errors, most of which have me take a look at the code and see what exactly the problem is. At this point I've made quite a few adjustments to the site to try and make it work that I feel continuing development won't get me anywhere.

Is duplicating an existing site to a local env usually this difficult? Could bad implementation of the initial site by the previous developer be a reason why I'm now struggling? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating a WordPress website is not that difficult. If you have the wp admin login of your website then you can simply use **duplicator** or **akeeba backup** plugin, but no worries, if you do not have the wp login access and just have the wp files & db then try this: create a new db from phpmyadmin, place your files in wp theme directory, install your new wp by using your new db file created, after that import your db file and do the following changes in your wp config file found in your root directory.

You will need to type in the new database information: database name, database user, and the password.

Once you have updated those, click Save Changes

*Fixing your Permalinks*

Log into your WordPress Dashboard, using the username and password from the copy of WordPress you brought over

Under Settings, click Permalinks

You don't have to make any actual changes, just click the Save Changes button.

Doing this will update all the page and post URLs. If you have custom themes or plugins/widgets with old URLs, you will have to update those manually since there are not any plugins that are able to modify those as well.

For ref:

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2361

https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-easily-import-or-export-any-of-your-wordpress-database-content-using-phpmyadmin-3415